# Where are the test packages for Android TV?

Tags: unit-testing, android-tv, amazon-fire-tv

I'm starting my first FireTv app in Android Studio and noticed that if I choose Android TV as a new project template, it does not come with the test packages like the phone & tablet templates do, ex: com.company.app (test), com.company.app (androidTest). I've looked through the Android TV [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/start) and Fire TV [docs](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/fire-tv/creating-media-streaming-app.html) but have not found a mention of the testing packages. Does anyone know why these packages aren't included or how to test without them?

Comment: Still not sure why the test packages aren't included, but I followed https://developer.android.com/studio/test/advanced-test-setup to add them manually.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, writing tests for your code can be as important as writing the code itself. Testing can help ensure that your product runs the way it should, and also provides useful information for when you’re trying to debug your code. In this guide, we’ll be examining a few ways to get started in Android testing with an example project called PowerUp, an educational mobile game app for preadolescent girls created by the Systers Community. Since this is an open source project, you can contribute to PowerUp on GitHub if you’re interested after reading this guide (remember to contribute to the GSoC17 branch, not develop)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).